# permission denied : copy / writing file (laravel / php)

Tags: php, laravel, file, permissions, remote-server

I use on my application some fonctions about files. creation of files, copy/create from a directory to another, update. On my localhost, all is okay, that's work.

The main purpose is to have a manager for translation on the website.

- rights of parent directories : 755

I have error :
1) if files doesn't exist the error is 
copy(/blabla/path.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied

2) if I create files before (touch + chown on usr:usr) with basic rights (644) or with updated rights (775) :
file_put_contents(/blabla/path.php) : failed to open stream: Permission denied

On my localhost :

- right of directories : 755
- right of files : 644

I also tried to clean php cache (php artisan cache:clear)

edit :

I use 2 functions : 
copy (who copy default translate file in the directory of second langage) and file_put_contents (who edit file)

```
public function replaceSlugs(Array $slugs,$filename, $lang)
    {
        $file=$this->path2File($filename,$lang);
        if(!file_exists($file)){$this->duplicateFile($lang,$filename);}
        $translate="<?php return ".var_export($slugs,true).";";
        return file_put_contents ( $file , $translate, LOCK_EX );
    }


    private function duplicateFile($lang,$filename)
    {
        copy($this->path2File($filename),$this->path2File($filename,$lang));
    }

    private function path2File($filename,$lang="en")
    {
        return resource_path('lang/'.$lang.'/'.$filename.'.php');
    }
```

Comment: Provide code or command which you use.

Comment: I edited my question with code.

Answer (score -1):

Solution is Risky but it will do the trick

Give your folders full permission & clear Cache

Something like this.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 public/lang/en
```

if you don't give 777 permission you will also stuck while unit Test.

Comment: what;s other than 777, seem scary, and hard to convince the crowd its not